# Find lists which together contain all values from 0-23 in list of lists python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists. The lists within these list look like the following:

```
[0,2,5,8,7,12,16,18], [0,9,18,23,5,8,15,16], [1,3,4,17,19,6,13,23],
[9,22,21,10,11,20,14,15], [2,8,23,0,7,16,9,15], [0,5,8,7,9,11,20,16]
```

Every small list has 8 values from 0-23 and there are no value repeats within a small list.

What I need now are the three lists which have the values 0-23 stored. It is possible that there are a couple of combinations to accomplish it but I do only need one.

In this particular case the output would be:

```
[0,2,5,8,7,12,16,18], [1,3,4,17,19,6,13,23], [9,22,21,10,11,20,14,15]
```

I thought to do something with the order but I'm not a python pro so it is hard for me to handle all the lists within the list (to compare all).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is setting off my NP-Hard alarm.

Comment: I think there is a pretty fast algorithm because you only need to find a combination of 3 of them and they fail pretty quickly (as soon as there is a single overlapping value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following appears to work:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

lol = [[0,2,5,8,7,12,16,18], [0,9,18,23,5,8,15,16], [1,3,4,17,19,6,13,23], [9,22,21,10,11,20,14,15], [2,8,23,0,7,16,9,15], [0,5,8,7,9,11,20,16]]

for p in combinations(lol, 3):
    if len(set((list(chain.from_iterable(p))))) == 24:
        print(p)
        break     # if only one is required
```

This displays the following:

```
([0, 2, 5, 8, 7, 12, 16, 18], [1, 3, 4, 17, 19, 6, 13, 23], [9, 22, 21, 10, 11, 20, 14, 15])
```

Answer (score 3):

If it will always happen that 3 list will form numbers from 0-23, and you only want first list, then this can be done by creating combinations of length 3, and then set intersection:

```
>>> li = [[0,2,5,8,7,12,16,18], [0,9,18,23,5,8,15,16], [1,3,4,17,19,6,13,23], [9,22,21,10,11,20,14,15], [2,8,23,0,7,16,9,15], [0,5,8,7,9,11,20,16]]

>>> import itertools
>>> for t in itertools.combinations(li, 3):
...     if not set(t[0]) & set(t[1]) and not set(t[0]) & set(t[2]) and not set(t[1]) & set(t[2]):
...         print t
...         break
([0, 2, 5, 8, 7, 12, 16, 18], [1, 3, 4, 17, 19, 6, 13, 23], [9, 22, 21, 10, 11, 20, 14, 15])
```

Comment: @joanbm Ok, yes. `combinations` should be fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a recursive solution.

We need a list of lists that contain these values:

```
target_set = set(range(24))
```

This is a function that recursively tries to find a list of lists that match exactly that set:

```
def find_covering_lists(target_set, list_of_lists):
    if not target_set:
        # Done
        return []

    if not list_of_lists:
        # Failed
        raise ValueError()

    # Two cases -- either the first element works, or it doesn't
    try:
        first_as_set = set(list_of_lists[0])
        if first_as_set <= target_set:
            # If it's a subset, call this recursively for the rest
            return [list_of_lists[0]] + find_covering_lists(
                target_set - first_as_set, list_of_lists[1:])
    except ValueError:
        pass  # The recursive call failed to find a solution

    # If we get here, the first element failed.
    return find_covering_lists(target_set, list_of_lists[1:])
```